# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How do you debug a custom workflow using CRM online?

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

We are using the online version of CRM. I have created a custom workflow but I can't seem to locate anything that will tell me how to debug it. Everything I've read refers to copying the pdb file into the server bin/assemblies folder. Since we're not using the on-premise version I'm not sure where to go from here. Can anyone point me to some type of documentation to do this?

Comment: Please mark the answer as "the answer" if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer this post to debug Custom Workflow in CRM Online.

[Click here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/microsoftdynamicscrmandstuff/archive/2013/03/08/debugging-workflow-custom-activities-with-plugin-registration-tool.aspx#.UaXnotKkprp)

Comment: Thanks, I knew you could profile a plugin but not a workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `ITracingService`, which is more like `alert("I'm here!")` rather than proper debugging.

In any case it's just like debugging a plugin and is described here: [Debug a Plug-In - Logging and Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx#loggingandtracing)

> An alternative method to debug a plug-in is to use tracing. Tracing
>   assists developers in troubleshooting plug-ins by providing run-time
>   plug-in information as an aid in diagnosing the cause of plug-in
>   failure. Tracing is especially useful to debug Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   Online registered plug-ins as it is the only supported debugging
>   method for that scenario.
>
> ...
>
> The tracing service was implemented to provide sandboxed plug-ins and
>   custom workflow activities with a means to output run-time information
>   when an exception is thrown.